# File Transferring through WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, file-upload

Consider the following contracts

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(CcmFaultException))]
void UploadStream(DataFileStream input);`

[MessageContract]
public class DataFileStream
{
    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public String FileName { get; set; }

    [MessageHeader(MustUnderstand = true)]
    public long FileSize { get; set; }

    [MessageBodyMember(Order = 1)]
    public Stream StreamData { get; set; }
}
```

I do have two major problems with it.

First issue is in service side which I cannot change the `UploadStream` signature, when I change the method signature in both interface and related class (for example adding return type or more input parameters), I can build the service but when I run the host application I get the following error:

> [System.InvalidOperationException]
>   The operation UploadStream either has a parameter or a return type that is attributed with MessageContractAttribute.
>   In order to represent the request message using a Message Contract, the operation must have a single parameter attributed with ...

Another issue is in client side, even if I use the `UploadStream(DataFileStream data)` contract
I can create an object of `DataFileStream` class, but when I want to call the `UploadStream` method I cannot pass the object! And the only option I see is the following signature in client side:

```
UploadStream(string FileName, long FileSize, Stream StreamData);
```

Would you please give me a solution for both issues.

Thank you

P.S : I'm using the following configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="CCMService.Binding_ICcmWcfService" closeTimeout="00:10:00"
        openTimeout="00:10:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00"
        maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <reliableSession ordered ="false" inactivityTimeout ="00:05:00"
        enabled ="true" />
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
           realm="" />
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                   negotiateServiceCredential="true" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>

  <client>
    <endpoint address="https://localhost:8731/CCMService" 
              binding="wsHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration="CCMService.Binding_ICcmWcfService" 
      contract="CCMServiceRef.ICcmWcfService"
      name="CCMService.Binding_ICcmWcfService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
  </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Maybe read about MessageContract vs DataContract - MessageContract is designed to have these constraints.

Comment: @steve16351 : Please read the following post

Answer (score 0):

@Steve16351

Consider the following implementation in Client app

```
    private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       CCMServiceRef.DataFileStream obj = new CCMServiceRef.DataFileStream()
       {
          FileName = _FileName,
          StreamData = GetStream(_FilePath)
       };
       Program.serviceManager.Client.ImportScript(obj);
    }


    private Stream GetStream(string filePath)
    {
        System.IO.MemoryStream data = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
        System.IO.Stream str = File.OpenRead(filePath);
        str.CopyTo(data);
        data.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        byte[] buf = new byte[data.Length];
        data.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        return data;
    }
```

when I switch over to DataContract program compile and host app runs, but when I call the Service method ( Program.serviceManager.Client.ImportScript(obj) ) , program sits for minutes until inactivity timeout raises!
In fact, Service method never executed!